# bootstrap grid views with different heights and row filling first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view with unequal height grids.
My html code is like this

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
</div>
```

and my css is

```
.grid-container{
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
}
```

It is rendering view as 
[column filling first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XQLe.png)

But i want it as 
[row filling first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQEyN.png)

and i have tried with col-md classes but it is making all the grids equal size but i want with unequal heights.
My entire html divs are dynamic from javascript

Comment: Not sure you can do that with only bootstrap, you probably need to deal with JS and masonry.

Comment: I hope this link useful http://htmlasks.com/best_way_to_arrange_layout_blocks